# How to merge part files in Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-composer

I have case in which I might have part files more than 400 ( result of big query export) in Google cloud storage. My business case needs, merge all these into one single output file. I tried gsutil compose but stuck with two issues.

1. It can only handle 32 files at at a time. Now let say I may use a programmatic way to create a loop over chunks of 32 files, and I overcome this issue still it leads another one
2. There will be multiple headers, since I am not flagging off include_headers option in BQ export (because I need header in output file)

Feels like I need a tricky solution, without downloading these into somewhere. Because if I choose a solution like that, it may result into extra resource utilisation ( I may ready to do if there is no other solution)

Note:I could have used dataflow to export data from bq to a single file. Since we are orchastrating this task through cloud composer, we used bq operator rather than dataflow, the later one is a complicated one:

Can anyone tell a better approach here ?

Comment: It's better to go with Dataflow solutions instead of Composer. Composer is just for orchestration part and not meant to merge multiple files. In Dataflow you just need to read file and write it in another GCS directory.
Note: Use withoutsharding()  option while writing file to gcs.

Comment: @miles212 Initially I thought about dataflow, still I am feeling the same, one limitation to go with dataflow is, we are generating these Airflow pipelines using Jinja2 templating and automated all the tasks. So users (BI team) doesn't need to worry much about coding here. At the same time if we go with dataflow, even we may get hack around to generate those pipelines, still there will be difficulties to launch pipelines. Because dataflow pipelines are not easy to launch and destroy like Airflow dags.